# Get rid of Fontawesome icon backgrounds in Omnigraffle

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

I'm using icons from Font Awesome in a current project. I've got the font installed on my PC and have used it in other applications (ie: illustrator, indesign, photoshop) without any problems. Basically, I would go to the [Font Awesome examples page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) to copy an icon and then paste it into my desktop application.

My current project requires Omnigraffle and I'm noticing a problem with the display of the icon. When I paste any icon into Omnigraffle from the examples page, a white background shows up behind the icon.

[image: Here's a screenshot to show what I mean.]

Has anyone encountered this and know how to get rid of the white background?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I just came across this problem myself and managed to solve it.

When you paste the icon in from the FontAwesome cheatsheet it has a white background. Changing font settings and colours etc seems to make no difference, but you can simply highlight your newly pasted in icon within Omnigraffle, copy it and then paste it again.

Not sure why this works, but the white background seems to be removed and you can then edit it as normal text.